# How can I see my state in Redux Dev Tools (Extension)?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I'm having trouble seeing my state in the Redux Dev Tools.  I added the code from zalmoxisus into my createStore, but nothing is displayed.  In my reducers I'm also returning the state as a default (using switch case) but still nothing is displayed in state.  Can anyone help with this?

[image: code for the store]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help displaying and seeing state in Redux Dev Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65528025/need-help-displaying-and-seeing-state-in-redux-dev-tools)

Answer (score 1):

try this to use this:

```
window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
```

instead of:

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import gamesReducer from ... //

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  gamesReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

You used rootReducer like this right?
If it is try redux-devtools-extension package, easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

export const middleware = [thunk]

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant()),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f,
    ),
  )
}
```