# Need help displaying and seeing state in Redux Dev Tools

Tags: redux, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I posted before, and thought I'd try one more time, since I still haven't got this to work.  I'm trying to get my state displayed on Redux Dev Tools (Extension).  I have got the code over from the zalmoxisus GitHub, but it still doesn't seem to be working.  If anyone can guide me on this, and knows how to work the Dev Tools extension, it would be a great help!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are not using [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers#arguments) correctly, would provide correct code but can't copy code from an image so won't do it.

Comment: Ah yes.  Thank you for the help !